# Is it possible to change the ip settings for ap0?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, gateway

I was wondering if it's possible to change the gateway IP of ap0 to like 192.168.43.2 so while the device is working as a hotspot some other apps on your network would detect your device.
but also it would work if I can sort of link both 192.168.43.1 and 192.168.43.2 with each other.

Comment: You can manually assign an IP to any interface as well as configure DNSMASQ to reserve a specific IP for DHCP server when hotspot is turned on.

Comment: @IrfanLatif well I have no idea how to do that can you please respond to this question so others can use it too that be great

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: @IrfanLatif of course it is i use lineage os with magisk